# node.js live server not booting admin error

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal

Whenever I try to boot up the server on visual code studio node.js keeps giving me this error. I tried running it on admin but it still gives me the same error. Can anyone shed some light on this?

```
PS C:\Users\amire\OneDrive\Desktop\javascript> live-server
live-server : File C:\Users\amire\AppData\Roaming\npm\live-server.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file C:\Users\amire\AppData\Roaming\npm\live-server.ps1 is not 
digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the current system. For more information about running scripts and setting execution policy, see 
about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ live-server
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Comment: I'm also trying to boot it on google chrome, idk if that makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because running scripts is disabled in your system, you need to set your execution policy to unrestricted. Follow these steps:

1. Open Powershell as admin: `Windows+r`, Then type `powershell` and `ctrl+shift+enter`
2. Then type this in PowerShell and press enter: `set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`
3. Select '*[A] Yes to All*': type `a` and press enter

Comment: this didnt work. I ran it on admin and when I typed in set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted it didn't do anything it just gave me another blank line and then I tried the third step and it said the term wasn't recognized.

Comment: a : The term 'a' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ a
+ ~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (a:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).